# Headless CMS as part of wider tech ecosystem

Tags: tree, authorization, content-management-system, rbac

I have a question about architecture with a CMS that I haven't really found a good resource for, so thought I'd throw it to the community.

My org is hoping to shift our current content tree structure from our internal database to a headless CMS, which should allow some of our non-tech stakeholders the ability to more easily edit content. We currently store our content in one table, and through relationships in another table. We create and cache the trees whenever users request content.

There are quite a few solutions out there that pretty much do what we want regarding content storage and relationships, but I'm currently trying to think through a couple of questions:

- How have other developers succeeded in using a CMS as part of a wider tech ecosystem, especially when other services/infrastructure are handling (or already handle) user authentication?
- Are there "good" CMS solutions out there ("good" = robust API, well-supported, open-source, etc.) that give granular control over content authorization on an item-level basis that doesn't involve completely re-inventing logic that already exists for auth elsewhere?

The reason is our content trees are a bit entangled. There's one for each product, and content may be shared across these products. i.e., user A has purchased product A, so can access a tree with root item A, but user B, who has not purchased that product, can't. But user B can access the tree with root item B, which might contain some of the content in product A's tree.

We have some current checks in our code for this auth, and I have yet to find a CMS that easily defines access control beyond a content/collection type structure. A CMS like Strapi/Keystone/Payload does allow control over collection/content-type. But I'm worried about separation-of-concerns. We still want to maintain our current API for other services, and not sure if reinventing the wheel too much with custom auth within the CMS. Shouldn't the CMS focus mostly on the content storage with some basic RBAC?

It is possible/likely I am overthinking things here, but this also doesn't seem like too crazy a use-case for existing CMS solutions out there.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

We use Payload CMS over a year now, and we love it!!!

You can implement your own auth strategy: (https://payloadcms.com/docs/authentication/config#strategies)

The way how access control is build is also awesome:
(https://payloadcms.com/docs/access-control/collections)

And to top it all off, you don't need to manage your: Admin UI, data structure and API. Just define your fields and the rest out of the box!
(https://payloadcms.com/docs/fields/overview)

Access control is also reflected in the API and admin UI.